# Trouble writing a yahtzee program

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I am in a beginner's java class. I have had this yahtzee program now for 3 weeks and I still cannot get this figured out. I need to roll 5 die twice seeing if I get a yahtzee (5 die the same) I am having trouble saving my die in the first roll to roll again My code is as follows. I'm sure there are many things that can be simplified(if into switch statements) but right now I'm concerned with getting these methods to work.

Our teacher provided us a die class to use as follows

```
public class Die
{
   private final int MAX = 6;  // maximum face value

   private int faceValue;  // current value showing on the die

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Constructor: Sets the initial face value.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public Die()
   {
      faceValue = 1;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Rolls the die and returns the result.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int roll()
   {
      faceValue = (int)(Math.random() * MAX) + 1;

      return faceValue;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Face value mutator.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public void setFaceValue(int value)
   {
      faceValue = value;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Face value accessor.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int getVal()
   {
      return faceValue;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns a string representation of this die.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public String toString()
   {
      String result = Integer.toString(faceValue);

      return result;
   }
}
```

My Yahtzee Code.

```
    import java.util.*;

public class Yahtzee 
{

    int a, b, c, d, e;

    Die die1 = new Die();
    Die die3 = new Die();
    Die die4 = new Die();
    Die die5 = new Die();
    Die die2 = new Die();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> dice2;

    int arrayLength;







    Die[] dice = new Die[5];

    //Constructor

    public Yahtzee()
    {


        for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i ++)
        {
            dice[i] = new Die(); 
        }
    }

    public void roll()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i ++)
        {
            dice[i].roll(); 
        }
    }


    public void saveDice()
    {
        dice2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i ++)
        {
            dice[i].getVal();
            for(int i2 = 0; i2 < dice.length; i2 ++)
            {
                if(i != i2)
                {
                    if(dice[i] == dice[i2])
                    {
                        dice2.add(dice[i].getVal()); 
                        dice2.add(dice[i2].getVal());
                         a = dice[i].getVal();


                         if(a == 5)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You have " + dice2.size() + "6's");
                        }
                         else if(a == 5)
                         {
                             System.out.println("You have " + dice2.size() + "5's");
                         }
                         else if(a == 4)
                         {
                             System.out.println("You have " + dice2.size() + "4's");
                         }
                         else if(a == 3)
                         {
                             System.out.println("You have " + dice2.size() + "3's");
                         }
                         else if(a == 2)
                         {
                             System.out.println("You have " + dice2.size() + "2's");
                         }
                         else if(a == 1)
                         {
                             System.out.println("You have " + dice2.size() + "1's");
                         }



                         b = dice2.size();
                    }


                    if(dice2.size() == 0)
                    {

                        if(a == 6)
                        {
                            System.out.println("No dice are the same. We kept 6 because its the largest face value.");

                        }
                        else if(a == 5)
                        {
                            System.out.println("No dice are the same. We kept 5 because its the largest face value.");
                        }
                        else if(a == 4)
                        {
                            System.out.println("No dice are the same. We kept 4 because its the largest face value.");

                        }
                        else if(a == 3)
                        {
                            System.out.println("No dice are the same. We kept 3 because its the largest face value.");

                        }
                        else if(a == 2)
                        {
                            System.out.println("No dice are the same. We kept 2 because its the largest face value.");

                        }
                        else if(a == 1)
                        {
                            System.out.println("No dice are the same. We kept 1 because its the largest face value.");

                        }
                    }

                    }

                }
        }
    }





    public void rollAgain()
    {
        arrayLength = dice2.size();
        System.out.println(arrayLength);


    }






}
```

my roll again method is not complete as my save dice does not work.

My driver is as follows but does nothing so far in the output which is part of my problem

```
public class YahtzeeFinal 
{

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Yahtzee yaht = new Yahtzee();

        yaht.roll();

        yaht.saveDice();

    }


}
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: For starters, your `roll()` method is pointless since it runs through a loop and merely calls `roll()` over and over again without ever assigning a value to anything. Also you call a `getVal()` method that, so far as I can see, doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm sorry. I use a another class with this one. I will edit my post and add that.

Comment: And it should automatically keep the dice with the most matches, correct? Or should it ask the user which dice to keep? Main reason I ask is your code appears to try and keep them automatically, but you declare a `Scanner` in your code that then goes unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you got your code working yet, or if you're still working on it, but here is what I came up with. I had a bit of fun with it. As you may notice, I tried to simplify certain parts of the code you had, so maybe you'll find some of this useful :) If you do use some of this and run into issues with it, let me know and I'll take another look.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Yahtzee {

    ArrayList<Die> savedDice = new ArrayList<Die>();

    // Constructor

    public Yahtzee() {
    }

    // renamed method to avoid confusion
    public void rollDice(int num) {
        Die[] dice = new Die[num];
        for (int d = 0; d < dice.length; d++) {
            Die nextDie = new Die();
            nextDie.roll();
            dice[d] = nextDie;
        }

        saveDice(dice);
    }

    public void saveDice(Die[] dice) {
        // int array will count occurrences of each face value
        int[] values = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        for (Die d : dice) {
            values[d.getVal() - 1]++;
        }
        int most = -1;
        int temp = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
            if (values[j] >= temp) {
                most = j + 1;
                temp = values[j];
            }
        }

        // Thought something like this looked much cleaner than having conditions for each value.
        if (temp > 1) {
            System.out.println("You have " + temp + " " + most + "'s");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No dice are the same. We kept " + most
                + " because it's the largest face value.");
        }

        for (Die d : dice) {
            if (d.getVal() == most) {
                savedDice.add(d);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is obviously correct but I (personally) would advice discretion giving direct answers when the problems are homework related.

Answer (score 1):

From your code it seems that `saveDice()` is trying to automatically save the best configuration for another role. When facing problems like this always try to manually run through your code with examples.

For example what will happen if `dice = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` and what will happen if `dice = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3}` (Think about this second one).

What I would suggest is to think more carefully about the algorithm first. For example if the goal of your algorithm is **Keep the dice with the highest occurring number**, then you need to think about how to get there step by step. I would start something like:

1. I need a way of tracking which dice will reroll and which wont.
2. I need to count the number of times each number (1 to 6) appears when I roll.
3. I need to make sure I only reroll the dice which do not match the number I got from step 2.

From these two simple points you could reach the following:

```
public static void Main(String []){
    Yahtzee game = new Yahtzee();
    game.roll();
    game.saveHighest();
    game.reroll();
}
public Yahtzee{
    // A boolean may help me save which dice to roll ?
    boolean [] saved = new boolean[5];

    public Yahtzee(){
        //initialise saved to false;
    }

    ...
    public void saveHighest(){
        int highestOccuringNumber = getHighest();
        for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i ++){
            if(highestOccuringNumber == dice[i]){
                saved[i] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    //Nothing complicated just need to get the highest number
    public int getHighest(){
        //Loop through and get the number which occurs most often
        // For example dice={1,1,2,3,4}. Highest = 1;
        //If no number occurs more than once just return highest occurring number
        //For example dice={1,2,3,4,5}. Highest = 5;
    }

    ///Reroll what isn't saved
    public void reroll(){
        for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i ++){
            if(!saved[i]){
                dice[i].roll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please be aware that the code above is **not** the most optimal way to execute this problem. It is here to serve as an example of how breaking down a problem piece by piece will help you come up with solutions.

Hopefully this will get you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This will help me getting there.

Comment: @Todd Glad I could help. I am just trying to demonstrate how breaking down the problem can lead to simple solutions. Optimizations can come later when you have a better understanding on the problem.